# Why access modifier in property accessors should be more restrictive than the property itself?

Tags: c#

While developing my application, I sometimes come to the point that I need a property that is currently, say private, but maybe later while we need to handle new scenarios, we may need to make it, say public. But, even if that is going to happen, I always want the setter to remain private. I want to write code like this:

```
private int A
{
  get{return _a;}
  private set {_a = value;}
}
```

The compilers complains that the access modifier on setter should be more restrictive than the property. Well I need to remove the access modifier on set, but if later I need to promote the property to public, I'll expose its setter as well.

Don't you think that this was better as a warning instead of an error?

Answer (score 4):

If you are changing the code to say `public` you can also change the code to say `private set` at the same time.

As for this being a warning, I can see it making some sense - I don't think anything would fail to work for only having specified `private` twice (though it is obviously pointless).  That said, I very rarely run into this compiler error and when I do I spent the 5 seconds it takes to fix it and move on.

<sub>The irony of the situation being that both of us have now spent longer on this question and answer than we likely *ever* have with this error and it's effects :-)</sub>

Comment: The point in the question is: I may need to make it public 3 months later, or even someone else may need to change it, when I've forgotten/he doesn't know the fact that its setter should be private.

Comment: @Alireza I know what the point is, but it isn't the task of the compiler or even the IDE to help you do the most minimal change possible when you edit code. If it is important that it remains private, create a test for it or don't use the type directly, instead use an interface (which cannot expose private members).

Comment: I agree, but I believe that the compiler is speculating on something it should not. 
I'll try to explain: 
Suppose in the design process we want the property to be protected, also we want it to be settable privately. These are totally different requirements and the compiler respects that. Now if both requirements become private, they are still two different requirements, but the compiler is no longer happy with that.

Comment: @Alireza Then in this instance you would know your requirements and write the code accordingly. The compiler is not stopping you from coding those requirements, it is stopping you from coding it the way you want to code it. I don't know of any reason why it should cause an error as opposed to a warning, but now it works this way I can see plenty for leaving it alone.

Comment: You are right. I usually try to foresee the future changes and write the code in a way that the chance of mistakes becomes minimal. I try to take as much out of the product as possible. This is where I love Microsoft's products. Any other component/library I've ever seen stops you by making unnecessary assumptions about the way you'll use their product. this is minimal in c# and .Net class library. This is one of the very rare instances.

Answer (score 2):

> Don't you think that this was better as a warning instead of an error?

No, I think you'd better use private variables (`private int _a;`) and only promote it to a property with the appropriate modifers when that is required.

Of course, without having a setter, you can't use validation like this:

```
private int _a;
public int A
{
    get { return _a; }
    private set { 

        if (value < 0 || value > 10)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("A");
        }

        _a = value; 
    }
}
```

But on the other hand, it doesn't hurt to mark the property being public in the first place, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Changing both modifiers is perfectly valid, so I would not bother much about the privat setter:

```
public int A
{
  get{return _a;}
  private set {_a = value;}
}
```

This is just my ***guess*** that the warning comes from the way the compiler re-writes the properties into IL code. The properties will be written as each a getter and setter method with the same modifier as the property itself.

If you now try to define a private setter of a private property, this would translate into:

```
private private get_A()
{
   return _a;
}
```

And this doubled private modifier would clearly not compile.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example doesn't make sense.  The setter is private as well if your property is private.  you only need to specify the access modifier on the setter, if the setter has to have another access modifier then the getter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to do the following...

```
private int _a;
public int A
{
    get { return _a; }
    private set { _a = value; }
}
```

This makes the get accessor public but the set private.